# How do I disable avx instructions on a linux computer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, avx

Or more specifically, how do I ensure that /proc/cpuinfo and the CPUID opcode do not show that AVX is enabled?

(For context, there is a bug on some Amazon EC2 instances, where AVX is falsely reported as active which causes programs that dynamically use AVX instructions to crash with SIGILL).

I've seen this kernel patch: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1521191/, but I'm not sure if that affects just the kernel's avx usage or also patches up CPUID and /proc/cpuinfo. Regardless, I am hoping to find a solution that works on the linux 2.6.x kernel series.

Comment: Mount proc elsewhere, symlink everything else than cpuinfo to `/proc` and store a customized file called `cpuinfo` in the `/proc` directory.

Comment: Add `noxsave` to your kernel boot options (e.g. at the end of the linux line in Grub) when you boot.  This will disable AVX.

Comment: Add `clearcpuid=156` to you kernel boot options. NB: there is no options to disable respective CPUID flags but well-behaving applications check also XCR0 which changes. See [Are the xgetbv and CPUID checks sufficient to guarantee AVX2 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522885) for some additional information about XCR0.